# How to handle binary datatype while using Spark CDM connector in Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-synapse

I am trying to read F&O data with Spark CDM Connector but currently facing an error of Binary datatype. I do not want to define the schema myself as there are 30 tables is there any other solution?

```py
DataFrame = spark.read.format("com.microsoft.cdm").option("storage",StorageName)\
.option("manifestPath",manifestPath).option("entity",entityName)\
.option("mode","permissive").load()
```

```
An error occurred while calling o3947.load.: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value found for 'Binary'
at scala.Enumeration.$anonfun$withName$1(Enumeration.scala:157)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.getOrElse0(HashMap.scala:596)
at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap.getOrElse(HashMap.scala:73)
at scala.Enumeration.withName(Enumeration.scala:157)
```

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Comment: I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

From the [Spark CDM connector docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/data-sources/apache-spark-cdm-connector#mapping-data-types-from-spark-to-common-data-model):

> The connector applies the following data type mappings when you convert Common Data Model to or from Spark.

| Spark | Common Data Model |
| --- | --- |
| ShortType | SmallInteger |
| IntegerType | Integer |
| LongType | BigInteger |
| DateType | Date |
| Timestamp | DateTime (optionally Time) |
| StringType | String |
| DoubleType | Double |
| DecimalType(x,y) | Decimal (x,y) (default scale and precision are 18,4) |
| FloatType | Float |
| BooleanType | Boolean |
| ByteType | Byte |

> The connector doesn't support the Common Data Model Binary data type.

That last sentence is the relevant one. Seems like you have some `Binary` types, which are not supported by this connector. Is it possible to change your source data's types, or maybe to avoid reading in the `Binary` columns?